# How to stream video using AIR Flex Mobile SDK for Android?

Tags: android, air, flex-mobile

I am merely trying to stream a video file that's on the web in a Flex Mobile AIR project on an Android device (Nexus S).

my file format is H.264 .mp4 
i'm using a stageWebView loading a remote webpage that has a video tag with the video set as the source. it plays in the regular android browser,

the poster image shows up in AIR along with video controls but then when the play button is clicked, the poster image disappears yet no video plays indefinitely.

i've tried multiple videos, multiple codecs, it works on iOS, i feel like i'm taking crazy pills, has anyone been able to successfully stream video on AIR for Android?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using NetStream and Video?

Try implementing the solution from this post

[NetStream appendByte issue with h264 FLV. Video stops about two second before the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899170/netstream-appendbyte-issue-with-h264-flv-video-stops-about-two-second-before-th)

Be sure to read the comments and add the complete listener

```
_ustream.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onComplete );

  private function onComplete( e:Event ):void
  {
      _ns.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.END_SEQUENCE);
  }
```